# Can I perform individual MariaDB/MySQL database backups from RDS to S3 without using a separate server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

So I know I can create snapshots or backups from the AWS console, but this will backup the entire database. But can I back up individual database schemas from RDS to S3 without a separate server?